# Python: Can't add string at the end of the list

Tags: python, string, list

I'm trying to make a text based RPG and when I'm trying to shorten every possible input into one variable I can't end a list with string:

```
input_use = ["use ", "use the "]
...
input_press = ["press ", "press the ", input_use]
...
input_interact_button = input_press + "button"
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to build lists, then concatenate the lists onto existing values:

```
input_press = ["press ", "press the "] + input_use

input_interact_button = input_press + ["button"]
```

Demo:

```
>>> input_use = ["use ", "use the "]
>>> input_press = ["press ", "press the "] + input_use
>>> input_interact_button = input_press + ["button"]
>>> input_interact_button
['press ', 'press the ', 'use ', 'use the ', 'button']
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely:

```
input_interact_button = input_press + "button"
```

Now, `input_press` is a list...but `"button"` is a string! You're trying to mix a list and a string. When you call the plus(`+`) operator, you're basically saying "combine a list with a string". It's like trying to blend peanut butter and coconut in a blender! You need to do this:

```
input_interact_button = input_press + ["button"]
```

Now, you placed `"button"` inside a one-element list. So...now you're combining a list and another list. Works!